VSTO VB OnAction doesn't activate
I'm creating a VSTO VB On Visual Studio for MS Visio. I have created a Ribbon with buttons, all works well then I've made a DropDown and I want to get back the selected Item. So I created the OnAction into the XML File, and in the CutomRibbon.vb I've created the public sub with a MsgBox just to test the OnAction, but it doesn't react.
Here's the XML code:
<group id="MLED_Group" label="Mur LED">
                <button id="MLEDBtn" label="Insérer un Mur LED" onAction="MLEDBtn_Click" size="large" imageMso="AbstractAssociation"/>
                <dropDown id="ListeCabalge" label="N° de circuit :" onAction="OnColorChange" enabled="true">
                    <item id="Item1" label="Data 1"/>
                    <item id="Item2" label="Data 2"/>
                    <item id="Item3" label="Data 3"/>
                    <item id="Item4" label="Data 4"/>
                    <item id="Item5" label="Data 5"/>
                    <item id="Item6" label="Data 6"/>
                    <item id="Item7" label="Data 7"/>
                    <item id="Item8" label="Data 8"/>
                    <item id="Item9" label="Data 9"/>
                    <item id="Item10" label="Data 10"/>
                </dropDown>
                <button id="CMLEDBtn" label="Commencer le câblage" onAction="CMLEDBtn_Click"/>
                <button id="stopCablingButton" label="Arrêter le câblage" onAction="OnStopCablingClick"/>
</group>

And here's the VB code:
Public Sub OnColorChange(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox("Je viens dêtre appelé")
    'CablingColor = selectedId
End Sub

So I want the MsgBox to show up for the moment to make sure it work. I've tried to put the code in CustomRibbon.vb and into ThisAddIn.vb but still the same. I've also tried to change ByVal control As IRibbonControl for ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl. Same.

Did you try MessageBox.Show Method?

Yes I did, also doesn't work

What about System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show ?

I've tried and same, I also just tried to call a Sub that works for one of my buttons and same. Like the OnAction doesn't apply
